# Shall I use onload on the body tag or detect the URL?

Tags: javascript, html, url, onload

I have a JavaScript function that should only run on specific pages on a website.

The function lives in a seperate `script.js` file that is shared between every page on the site.

To ensure that this function only runs on a specific page I currently hard code the onload attribute to the body tag on the pages that I want it to run e.g. `<body onLoad="myFunction()">`

I was contemplating removing this and instead adding some code to my function whereby it gets the current URL and if it matches one of the URL's in a list of allowed URL's then it will run.

**Is it worth doing this or shall I retain the need to just add an onload attribute to each body tag?**

**Or is there a better solution to only run a function on specific pages?**

Comment: is there any specification of pages on which you want to call myfunction

Comment: Why not put a class on the `<body>` tag for pages that the script applies to?

Comment: @Somebody is in trouble at the moment it is just the homepage and one other sub page, but this could change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paul Irish has nice post on how to load scripts on needed pages, check out:

- [Markup-based unobtrusive comprehensive DOM-ready execution](http://paulirish.com/2009/markup-based-unobtrusive-comprehensive-dom-ready-execution/)

Comment: nice article, using data attributes could be the way to go (similar approach to adding a class or id).

Answer (score 1):

You can check the current url (`location.href`). However, it would be cleaner to have some identifier that you look for. Example:

```
<body id="thePageIwant">
</body>
```

Then:

```
$(function () {
    if ($('#thePageIwant').length > 0) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, I think i'll take a similar approach but use the data attribute rather than a class or id.